# How do I go about synchronously initialising my provider? (Riverpod)

Tags: flutter, state-management, riverpod

I have a provider like so:

```dart
final profileImagesProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider.family<ProfileImagesNotifier, List<String>>(
        (ref, profileImages) => ProfileImagesNotifier(profileImages));

class ProfileImagesNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  ProfileImagesNotifier(List<String> images);

  List<String> images;
}
```

However, when I try to use the provider:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
  var profileImages = watch(ProfileImagesNotifier(['test_1.png', 'test_2.png']))
  print(profileImages.images) //null
}
```

The list is retrieved as a null.

Am I doing this right? (I'm a completely noob when it comes to river pod and state management).

Comment: have you tried to do `ProfileImagesNotifier(List<String> this.images);` instead of `ProfileImagesNotifier(List<String> images);`?

Comment: @GilesCorreiaMorton That was it. How I didn't see that, i have no idea.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked! It's a very easy mistake to make especially when also learning how to structure and implement riverpod state management practises :)

Answer (score 0):

Was incorrectly calling the constructor.

Should have been:

```dart
ProfileImagesNotifier(this.images);
```

rather than

```dart
ProfileImagesNotifier(List<String> images);
```